# How to make sidebar?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, slide, sidebar

I am using C# programming language. 
I have created a new borderless Windows Form in Visual Studio 2012. I have two panels. First panel (***panel1***) is docked at top and second panel (***panel2***) is docked at left and its *Visible status* is *false*. I also added a button (***buttonMenu***) in panel1 and docked it on left. What I am trying to achieve is that on **buttonMenu** click, panel2 slides from left to its original location (***left dock***) and when **buttonMenu** clicked again slides away.

I have tried to set the following code:

```
private void buttonMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible;
    }
```

And it works but i am trying to make it slide with an animation.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to be *specific* and not just a list of requirements. Please see [Why is "Can Someone Help Me" not an "actual" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Win forms isn't really the way to go if you want a desktop application with fancy animations.

Comment: What should i use instead?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do it would be to create a timer and in its `Tick` event change the panel width like so

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();

bool closing = false;
int desiredWidth = 300
private void ConfigureTimer()
{
   timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
   timer.Interval = 16;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
{
   if(closing)
   {
      panel2.Width-=15;
      if(panel2.Width < 0) 
      {
        panel2.Width = 0;
        timer.Stop();
      }
   }else{
       panel2.Width+=15;
      if(panel2.Width >= desiredWidth) 
      {
        panel2.Width = desiredWidth;
        timer.Stop();
      }
   }
}

private void SwitchPanelState()
{
    closing = !closing;
    timer.Start();
}
```

> But if you want to make you life easy and more object oriented, you should create an Control with the specified behavior and just add it in your form

Comment: What are controls? I heard about user control but never really understood how should i use it.